# Non-independence of data points a problem when only doing model comparison?

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis, generalized-additive-model

I have a dataset that behaves sort of like time series data. It's 150 measurements in ~15000 individuals, with each measurement either a 0 or a 1 (failure or success). In addition, for each individual, I have a single measurement for a particular quantitative variable Z.

I want to know 1) if the distribution in time of successful trials depends on Z 2) if any such effect is merely additive or if there is an interaction between time and Z.

At the moment, I have fit three binary logistic regression GAMs. 1) success ~ time 2) success ~ time + Z 3) success ~ time * Z. Using AIC, I have determined that 3 is the best model.

However, I know that my approach is erroneous. I am modelling each trial as an independent data point although in actuality, it is not, as individuals that have successes at one time point are also more likely to have successes at other time points.

My question is, does this matter if I'm only doing model comparison? As in, if I was interested in parameter estimates, then of course this would be a bad approach. But if I'm just comparing between models, given that all of the models share this defect, it shouldn't matter for the comparison, right? I know that ideally, I should fit a multi-level model but with 15000 individuals, it just becomes very computationally expensive (especially as the relationship between time and the response variable is non-linear) and I'm not sure I would get much out of it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the repeated measures nature of the data, I would not at all be comfortable making conclusions about best fitting models without using methods appropriate for such data. If you are using `mgcv`, then you should check out Michael Clark's excellent [write up and comparison](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-10-20-big-mixed-models/) of R packages for estimating mixed models on big data. In particular, `bam()` within `mgcv` was designed with big data constraints in mind.

Can the time functional form be approximated with polynomial functions (i.e., $time, time^2, time^3, etc.$)? If so, you could feasibly fit the model using `glmer` or `glmmTMB` or [`GLMMadaptive`](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/). You may not need random effects for each of the highest-order polynomials as there may be diminishing returns. Also worth considering is whether there remains residual autocorrelation even after accounting for a person/subject random effect. That is not handled well in `glmer` but is in [`glmmTMB`](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/329). I'm not sure if `GLMMapadaptive` can deal with them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it's very helpful. I think bam in mgcv will do what I need it to do (and if I set the basis function type to "gp", that should help with the issue of autocorrelation that you mentioned, right?). But I'm getting a very strange issue that I've never come across in R. I run bam() and it looks like it finishes (I get the prompt back) but if I do summary(M) or just type M, it prints out nothing. And the model object doesn't appear in the RStudio environment pane. It's like the command finished but the resulting object was never generated.